# Modify CSS in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am a noob of jQuery, and I have tried the following code but doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to assign leftValue to "left" as following code using jQuery?

```
var i =0;
var leftValue = seat_xcoord*20;
$('#seat'+i).css({left: $leftValue});
```

Cheers.

Comment: any sizing values you set in css must have valid units. `100` by itself means nothing. pixels? inches? ems? ens? nanoparsecs?

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
$('#seat'+i).css({left: leftValue + 'px'});
```

You had **$leftValue**  instead of **leftValue**

And make sure there is element with `id="seat0"`

[Check DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ae9jj/)

Comment: And make sure there is an element with te id `seat0`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $ from your leftValue variable and concatenate "px" for pixel units.